# Oracle APEX ORDS

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to install and configure Oracle REST Data Services on the same machine running an Oracle database for development purposes, similar to the Embedded PL?SQL Gateway?

Comment: REST means the comunikation runs over http over a port of your selection, so even when oracles would answer on a web port, you can switch

Comment: Short answer: Yes, it can be done that way.

Answer (score 1):

The Embedded PLSQL Gateway is actual code inside the database via the XDB HTTP listener. That is not possible with ORDS.

ORDS is a java process that has a built-in webserver by leveraging Jetty (https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/ ). This allows ords to be run with just a single command like

```
java -jar ords.war standalone
```

This will start the webserver on the configured port and will allow OWA/PLSQL Gateway procedures to keep working as before.